# How can I make make css transition happen when applying width through javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I am using telerik controls to build a simple form.

The form will have 3 buttons.

1. 100 Dollar Button
2. 50 Dollar Button
3. Other button

The first and second button are actual RadButtons

```
    <telerik:RadButton ID="Donate100" runat="server" Text="$100" Width="70" CssClass="" Visible="true" OnClick="Donate100_Click"></telerik:RadButton>
    <telerik:RadButton ID="Donate50" runat="server" Text="$50" Width="70" CssClass="" Visible="true" OnClick="Donate50_Click"></telerik:RadButton>
```

And the third 'button' is just an input box that is styled to look like a button

```
<telerik:RadNumericTextBox ID="Other" Width="70" runat="server" Type="Currency" DisplayText="Other" Visible="true" OnTextChanged="Other_TextChanged">
    <ClientEvents OnFocus="Focus" />
</telerik:RadNumericTextBox>
```

When the user focuses on the 'other button' I call a javascript function that expands the width of the button.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function Focus(sender, eventArgs) {

        document.getElementById("Other_wrapper").style.width = "400px";
    }
</script>
```

This works perfectly. The only thing that I'm missing is how to do the transition. I'd like it to take 1.5 seconds to transition from the shorter width of 70px to 400px.

Does this need to be done via switching the css class? Instead of setting width manually with javascript? Or can I somehow add the transistion to my javascript function. The latter would be ideal.

Comment: Have you tried `transition: width 1.5s ease` in your CSS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's possbile with just Javascript. But it's also not recommended due to the maintainability issue.

```
var wrapper = document.getElementById("Other_wrapper");
wrapper.style.transition = 'width 1.5s ease';
wrapper.style.width = '70px';

function Focus(sender, eventArgs) {
  wrapper.style.width = "400px";
}
```

Using a class styled with css is preferred.

```
//CSS
#Other_wrapper {
  width: 70px;
  transition: width 1.5s ease;
}
.expand {
  width: 400px;
}
//JS
function Focus(sender, eventArgs) {
  document.getElementById("Other_wrapper").className += " expand";
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to add CSS3 transitions, for example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: width 2s;
}

div:hover {
    width: 300px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<p><b>Note:</b> This example does not work in Internet Explorer 9 and earlier versions.</p>

<div></div>

<p>Hover over the div element above, to see the transition effect.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple CSS3 transition to get the animation:

```
#Other {
    transition: width 1.5s;
}
```

Btw: You do not need any -webkit or similar prefix, since all current browsers support this behavior: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-transitions

**Tip:**

If the JS is only used to change the size of the textbox, then you can also remove the JS "onFocus" handler and use pure CSS instead:

```
#Other {
    width: 70px;
    transition: width 1.5s;
}
#Other:focus {
    width: 400px;
}
```